# Cygwin trouble running some bash commands

Tags: bash

Im having trouble with cygwin not running my script file as expected

here is my code

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Ja eller nei:"
read svar
if ["$svar" = "ja"]; then
    echo "Du er Positiv"
    exit 0
elif ["$svar" = "nei"]; then
    echo "Du er Negativ"
    exit 0
else
    echo "Du er Nøytral"
fi
```

and here is my outputin cygwin

```
$ /cygdrive/c/MyScripts/Bash.sh
Ja eller nei:
ja
': not a valid identifierh.sh: line 6: read: `svar
/cygdrive/c/MyScripts/Bash.sh: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `elif'
'cygdrive/c/MyScripts/Bash.sh: line 10: `elif ["$svar" = "nei"]; then
```

its the 3 last error lines i dont understand per say. i understand where the error's are but not why they are there.

BTW the reason im saying some is

```
for i in {1..100}; do echo $i; done
```

works properly

Comment: Add `set -x` to the beginning and be enlightened.

Comment: the beginning of my code? only gives me 
: invalid optionripts/Bash.sh: line 5: set: -
set: usage: set [--abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option-name] [arg ...]

Comment: `set -` is not the same as `set -x`, and you should put it on the first line after `#!/bin/sh`

Comment: @Thomas: `set -x` just turns on debugging at the shell prompt. You can get the same effect when running your script by running it with `bash -x /cygdrive/c/MyScripts/Bash.sh`

Comment: i wrote set -x not set - 

bash -x /cygdrive/c/MyScripts/Bash.sh worked though it gave me the same error's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try forming your test statements with correct spacing:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Ja eller nei:"
read svar
if [ "$svar" = "ja" ]; then
    echo "Du er Positiv"
    exit 0
elif [ "$svar" = "nei" ]; then
    echo "Du er Negativ"
    exit 0
else
    echo "Du er Nøytral"
fi
```

This is the output I get:

```
lnet@bowser ~ $:) sh test.sh
Ja eller nei:
ja
Du er Positiv
lnet@bowser ~ $:) sh test.sh
Ja eller nei:
nei
Du er Negativ
lnet@bowser ~ $:) sh test.sh
Ja eller nei:
fish
Du er N[G[Gøytral
lnet@bowser ~ $:(
```

---

**Update** (thanks Sorpigal):

Also, make sure your file has proper unix line endings:

```
dos2unix -f /cygdrive/c/MyScripts/Bash.sh
```

Comment: still no change, but acording to the error message the couprit i think is read svar but i dont see why

Comment: @ThomasAndreèLian: Your example has `if ["$svar"` which is certainly a syntax error. Are you sure what you posted is really what was executing?

Comment: Yes im sure its a direct copy/paste

hmm is /cygdrive/c/MyScripts/Bash.sh the correct way to open c:/MyScripts/Bash.sh ?

Comment: @ThomasAndreèLian: Are you perhaps saving with DOS-style line endings?

Comment: Yep, that will be it. @Thomas: I'll add the command to convert your file to the correct format to my answer...

Comment: DOS-style line endings? what is this? sorry for my ignorance

Comment: @Thomas: read this: http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~krueger/csc209h/tut/line-endings.html

Comment: ok i get that \r\n and \n is the difference but i have not written any \r\n or \n

Comment: You don't have to write them, your text editor writes them every time you create a new line. The problem is that Notepad (a windows program) will save them with `\r\n` and bash is expecting a file with just `\n`.

Comment: One way to be sure would be to chmod a+x your script and then invoke it directly, e.g. `/cygdrive/c/MyScripts/Bash.sh`  It should give "bad interpreter" in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but cygwin is bash. So try this instead :

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Ja eller nei:"
read svar

if [[ "$svar" == "ja" ]]; then
    echo "Du er Positiv"
    exit 0
elif [[ "$svar" == "nei" ]]; then
    echo "Du er Negativ"
    exit 0
else
    echo "Du er Nøytral"
fi
```

And to be sure you have a proper version, do this :

```
wget http://pastie.org/pastes/2880899/text
chmod +x text
./text
```

Answer (score 0):

```
read svar

': not a valid identifierh.sh: line 6: read: `svar
```

I'll bet the actual error message is something along the lines of:

```
`svar\r': not a valid identifer ...
```

Your script has Windows-style `"\r\n"` line endings.  Cygwin's `/bin/sh` requires Unix-style `"\n"` line endings.  The shell sees the `"read svar"` line, not as `"read svar"` followed by end-of-line, but as `"read svar"` followed by a CR (`'\r'`) character followed by end-of-line.  It tries to interpret `"svar\r"` as an identifier, and complains that it's invalid.

**EDIT :** I see that another answer already mentioned this.  I'm going to leave my answer here because I suggest some ways to verify the problem and to avoid it.

Try running `/cygdrive/c/MyScripts/Bash.sh | cat -A` to see what the error messages really look like.

Use something like `dos2unix` (I *think* that's the right command name) to fix the script's line endings.  (Read the man page first; unlike most Unixish filter commands, it replaces the named file rather than writing to stdout.)

One way to avoid this problem in the future is to compose your scripts using one of the text editors provided by Cygwin (vim, emacs, nano, whichever one you prefer).  If you want to use a Windows editor (notepad, Notepad++, ...), there might be a way to configure it to write Unix-style line endings.